# A column called 'id' was added to the attributes of 'table' but not marked with 'primaryKey: true

Tags: mysql, next.js, sequelize.js

Even with primaryKey: true the error "A column called 'id' was added to the attributes of 'users' but not marked with 'primaryKey: true"  is thrown.

The app was running ok till I turned it off yesterday, already with primary key: true setted.

```
export const users = connection.define("users", {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    senha: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    empresa_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true
    },
    isAdmin: DataTypes.TINYINT,
}, {
    freezeTableName: true
})
```

```
export default async function createUser(req = NextRequest, res = NextResponse) {
    let email = req.body.email
    let password = await hash(req.body.password)
    let isAdmin = 1

    await users.create({
        email: email,
        senha: password,
        isAdmin: isAdmin,
    }).then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        res.status(200).json({'response': 'Usuário criado com sucesso!'})
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(400).json({'response': 'Erro ao criar usuário.'})
    })
}
```

I tried all sync() options, but same error occurs.

Comment: Did you try dropping your tables and running the sync again?

Comment: @ShaileshB yep, actually I did it the day before cuz I had the same error, it worked till I turn off the pc, and started it next day.